# How to convert a Hive table into a MLlib LabeledPoint?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have used Impala to build a table that contains a target and hundreds of features.
I'd like to use Spark MLlib to train a model.
I understand that in order to run a distributed supervised model through Spark the data needs to be in one of several formats. LabeledPoint seems the most intuitive to me.
What is the most effective way to transform a Hive table into Labeled Points using PySpark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution to this problem is likely to use the ml library and it's models as they act directly on dataframes.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=ml#module-pyspark.ml.classification

However, ml api hasn't reached feature parity with mllib yet and something you need might be missing. So we solved this problem in our workflow by calling a map on the dataframe retrieved by the hive context.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, HiveContext
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.mllib.classification import LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS

table_name = "MyTable"
target_col = "MyTargetCol"

sc = SparkContext()
hc = HiveContext(sc)

# get the table from the hive context
df = hc.table(table_name) 

# reorder columns so that we know the index of the target column
df = df.select(target_col, *[col for col in dataframe.columns if col != target_col])

# map through the data to produce an rdd of labeled points
rdd_of_labeled_points = df.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row[0], row[1:]))

# use the rdd as input to a model
model = LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.train(rdd_of_labeled_points)
```

Keep in mind that any time you map with python, the data needs to be marshaled across from the JVM to the Python VM and that performance suffers because of this. We found that the performance hit from using a map was negligible for our data, but your mileage may vary.